# How can I fix a broken package in Debian?

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation

I am attempting to renew an SSH cert on my ReadyNAS, which runs Debian.  I suspect that a firmware upgrade a few months back that updated Apache and potentially other packages may have broken my Let's Encrypt renewal process, which runs nightly.  When the script runs, the following output occurs:

```
root@GeoffNAS:/home/admin# ./letsencrypt-renew.sh 
Bootstrapping dependencies for Debian-based OSes... (you can skip this with --no-bootstrap)
**(snip for brevity)**
virtualenv is already the newest version (15.1.0+ds-2+rnx1).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-virtualenv : Depends: python-pip-whl (>= 8.1.1-2) but 1.5.6-5 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@GeoffNAS:/home/admin#
```

When I run apt-get upgrade, I get the following:

```
root@GeoffNAS:/home/admin# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  python-pkg-resources
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages have been kept back:
  python3-virtualenv
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up nfs-kernel-server (1:1.2.8-9+deb8u1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
update-rc.d: error: initscript does not exist: /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server
dpkg: error processing package nfs-kernel-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nfs-kernel-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@GeoffNAS:/home/admin#
```

Any idea how to resolve this, by fixing the python3-virtualenv?  I need this functioning for my Let's Encrypt to renew automatically.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It looks like you're running Debian jessie ([python-pip-whl (1.5.6-5)](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python-pip-whl), [nfs-kernel-server (1:1.2.8-9+deb8u1)](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/nfs-kernel-server)), but your [python-virtualenv](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=python-virtualenv) package seems to be from 
Debian stretch or newer (dependency python-pip-whl >= 8.1.1-2). Please add the output of `lsb_release -a`, `apt-cache policy python-virtualenv python-pip-whl` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: First, if you are using jessie-backports on this system, please say so and give some details on how the backports are configured, as that may also help with diagnosing the problem. Second, the second error message says file `/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server` doesn't exist. Can you report back on whether or not this file exists on this computer?

Comment: I'm not using the Jessie backports - I forgot those were in there from an earlier adventure.  I've removed them from my sources.

Comment: @ender.qa - The file `/etc/linit.d/nfs-kernel-server` is not present

Comment: Output of lsb_release -a:

root@GeoffNAS:/etc/init.d# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.Distributor ID: Debian
Description: Debian GNU/Linux 8.11 (jessie)
Release: 8.11
Codename: jessie

Comment: [root@GeoffNAS:/etc/init.d# apt-cache policy python-virtualenv python-pip-whl
python-virtualenv:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 15.1.0+ds-2+rnx1
  Version table:
     15.1.0+ds-2+rnx1 500
        500 https://repos.rnxtras.com/debian/rnx-rnos6 rnx-rnos6/main armel Packages
python-pip-whl:
  Installed: 1.5.6-5
  Candidate: 1.5.6-5
  Version table:
 *** 1.5.6-5 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: deb https://apt.readynas.com/packages/readynasos 6.10.2 updates apps main

Comment: Two other sources had been present, but I added them manually while working on another issue, and have since removed them - I can add them back again if needed.
deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian jessie main
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

Answer (score 0):

I had a local friend I trust with root access to my machine log in directly and take a look.  He was able to resolve this, and it turned out to be several things combined.  For the sake of history, I'll summarize what he found here.

- Netgear ReadyNAS OS6 is, in fact, the same as Debian Jessie, and pulls from the Jessie repositories
- At some point in the past, I'd accidentally removed some of the Debian repositories while fixing another issue when Netgear pushed an update
- There was also a conflict between the official Debian / Netgear / Jessie repositories, and the repositories added by an add-on from a third party (rnxtras), which appears to pull from Stretch

My friend was able to untangle the repositories, remove and reinstall the correct version of the broken packages, and pin them so they would not pull from the wrong repository in the future.  Let's Encrypt now calls Apt without error, and updates the cert correctly.

Thank you for all your help!